# Association mapping for log level in log4j2 JdbcAppender ColumnConfig

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I have implemented the logging using 
http://smasue.github.io/log4j2-spring-database-appender

I want to add the association for the log level. i.e., moving the log levels to separate table as foundation data (ERROR = 1) and if pattern "%level" value is ERROR then I will use level_id as 1 in my logging table instead of ERROR.

Is it possible ? Can anyone please help me here.
Thanks